# Arduino with NFC: Garbled Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, shields, library

I started working on a small programming project just for fun and I have got stuck. I have been using the following tutorial to make an [Amiibo Music Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXTU7.jpg)

Now using the libraries the tutorial suggested, I successfully uploaded the sketch to the device. However when I put an Amiibo or NFC card on top and look at the Serial Monitor, I get lots of garble and no sound.

```
¸ý×ÿòœy_ÿ#À–Yÿ›l°   _Yÿ8dÐa4’ÿ’Í�©ÿ›—Lµ›ú’áo°)h@’öþ8‚¤hþ:dÐ S4ê’ÉãÈô›l°É�°ò“ƒc¶ÿ™l±a“ùü8‚´hþ›l°É�´÷“ÅiØð
¶–t=Üý’ÉãÈôâd@àÉ‘ø8‚¤hþ
–e¼Õý’ÍÐPÿK¬ÀàÉ�ú8�·i™–e¼Õý8©Pòý’t=Üý“ƒf–ÿü’t=Ø9UY6þ›hX Cú’Í�©ÿ(l„±Ô_ü8‚´hþKìAÀò ý:‚´hþ8lÐaÓ4â’ÌcÈõ›hX Cú“ƒf–ÿKìEÀò ý’ÌiØõ8lÐaâtý“ƒ&–ÿè4@’âþ“ƒ&–ÿš’L²µšý8�·yÿ)l„úÈï’ÉãÈõ(l„±Ô_ü’ÍÙ:dÐ`S4ê2"´žþ)l„úÈï2"ßŸÿ›h±ÑªÛÖ’áoÞÿüÒt=Ø‘�&’ÿ�šA’âþ“ƒc¶þ›l±ÑªËÓ’Í�©ÿ8lÐaâtý’ÍÙ
––\5,ÿ’Í�©ÿè4@àâþ8©Pòý–t=Üý:‚´hþ
––t=Üý8‚´hþ8l€a¢tý’ÉãÈõš’L²µšýÜ,þÍ›þëÖÿÜ,þÜ,ÿÜ,ÿYÿ\ÿëòÿÜ,þêëòÿëòÿê4KÖÿ\ÿ]ÓÜ,ÿ\
```

I tried the card that comes with the kit and it does not work either. Has anyone got any idea why this has failed? I have put a link to the libraries and code I am using below.

- https://github.com/ModusPwnin/Interactive-Amiibo-Stand
- https://github.com/ModusPwnin/Interactive-Amiibo-Stand/blob/master/Amiibo%20Stand%20v3
- https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C
- https://code.google.com/p/wavehc/

I am new to this but I want to understand why this is not working as well. Can anyone help me?